# Message: The type registry TypeRegistry

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm using grails 2.5.0 and mysql 8.0.13

```
    dbCreate = "create-drop"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bet?serverTimezone=UTC"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "root"
    password = "pepito"
```

For example, if I save a "Product", it's work, but if I change some code in any controller I got this error:

```
The type registry TypeRegistry(id=334490881,loader=groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader) does not know about type id 1839. 
Stacktrace follows:

Message: The type registry TypeRegistry(id=334490881,loader=groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader) does not know about type id 1839 

Spring Loaded: Cannot reload new version of com.bet.controller.AgentController
Reason: Interfaces changed from [org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/support/TransactionManagerAware, groovy/lang/GroovyObject] to [groovy/lang/GroovyObject]
```

Y tested in sql server and it's work

Comment: We'll probably need more information. Could you create a sample project and upload it to github to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Hi Joe, this issue only is in mysql the last version

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, I normally restart the application. When we change a lot in a controller, the application could not load the latest updated version of the compiled class according to that controller in some cases.

Comment: i reseted the tool, but when I start again and I change something, I got the error. If i change to sql server or oracle, it's works

Comment: Did you try to clean and restart the application?

Comment: yes, i think is because the last version mysql, I have changed url and driverclassname with respect another mysql versions